# Can't drop indexes with schema name

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-administration

Created index on partition table movies.actors_2010(name) with schemaname  movies.actors_2010_name_idx

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "movies.actors_2010_name_idx" ON movies.actors_2010(name);
```

Now when I try to drop the index, output shows index doesn't exist and index remain same, can't drop it.

```
drop index IF EXISTS movies.actors_2010_name_idx;
```

Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you quoted the identifier `"movies.actors_2010_name_idx"`. That created an index with a  `.` in the name, not an index named `"actors_2010_name_idx"` in the `movies` schema. To do that, you should have used

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "movies"."actors_2010_name_idx" ON "movies"."actors_2010"(name);
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY movies.actors_2010_name_idx ON movies.actors_2010(name);
```

---

Now to do delete the index with the broken name, you'd use

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "movies.actors_2010_name_idx";
```

or possibly

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "movies"."movies.actors_2010_name_idx";
```